# What did Earth’s timeline look like for Fitz and Enoch?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, agents-of-shield

Much of the fifth season is set

> in the future, where Daisy has destroyed the planet, and subsequently the Kree have taken over.

In previous episodes, characters floated the idea that this was an “alternate timeline” or “alternate universe,” one where Daisy was powerful enough to destroy the planet. However, Fitz and Enoch have been revealed to have gotten there the traditional way, i.e. by living through those events, albeit at a safe distance. Thus, it seems to be the same universe.

One presumes that eventually the destruction of Earth will be prevented or undone in some manner. So what does the timeline look like from Enoch and Fitz’s perspective?

- If it’s the timeline without Daisy, how was the Earth destroyed?
- If it’s the timeline with Daisy, after she comes back having fixed whatever needs to have been fixed (and presumably having prevented the destruction of the Earth), again, how was the Earth destroyed?

(Obviously, a timeline where Daisy comes back from the future and then somehow becomes powerful enough to destroy the planet makes perfect sense, but is extremely unlikely to be the case).

Comment: Since it hasn't been revealed yet, wouldn't this fall under future work and be off-topic?

Comment: @RemyLebeau - That depends. My guess is that it *has* been revealed, or hinted at, or discussed in an interview.

Comment: “One presumes that eventually the destruction of Earth will be prevented or undone in some manner” — you’re crazy. They can’t just [rewind time](http://marvelcinematicuniverse.wikia.com/wiki/Eye_of_Agamotto)!